# Wordpress Nav Walker - Multilevel navigation

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I need help with navigation in Wordpress site. I'm trying to get Wordpress print my navigation in this format:

```html
<ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1" href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-2" href="#">Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-3" href="#">Grains</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-4" href="#">Mylk & Drinks</a></li>
      </ul>
      
<!-- Submenu 1 / Shown when user clicks the first list item (item with data-submenu="submenu-1") on data-menu="main" -->
      <ul data-menu="submenu-1" class="menu__level">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Stalk Vegetables</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Roots & Seeds</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Cabbages</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Salad Greens</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Mushrooms</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-1-1" href="#">Sale %</a></li>
      </ul>
      
<!-- Submenu 2 / Shown when user clicks the second list item (item with data-submenu="submenu-2") on data-menu="main" -->
      <ul data-menu="submenu-2" class="menu__level">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Citrus Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Berries</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-2-1" href="#">Special Selection</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Tropical Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Melons</a></li>
      </ul>
      
<!-- Submenu 3 / Shown when user clicks the third list item (item with data-submenu="submenu-3") on data-menu="main" -->
      <ul data-menu="submenu-3" class="menu__level">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Buckwheat</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Millet</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Quinoa</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Wild Rice</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Durum Wheat</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-3-1" href="#">Promo Packs</a></li>
      </ul>
      
<!-- Submenu 4 / Shown when user clicks the forth list item (item with data-submenu="submenu-4") on data-menu="main" -->
      <ul data-menu="submenu-4" class="menu__level">
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Grain Mylks</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Seed Mylks</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Nut Mylks</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Nutri Drinks</a></li>
        <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-4-1" href="#">Selection</a></li>
      </ul>
```

But I can't figure out how to specify child items to specific parent item and then printing them with data-submenu.

**Navigation structure is taken from here:
http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/MultiLevelMenu/**

Thanks!

Update: This crossed my mind: would it be easier or cleaner to just get navigation data with php and then populate it in right format with Javascript? Does anyone know if this would be better way to handle this?

Or how about using rest-api with this (I'm fairly new with this, so is there point to use it as a part of in small website project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can just grab all menu data (from certain location) into the array & output it any way you like.

For example, you have menu structure like this:

```
Menu_parent1_item
    Submenu_item_1
    Submenu_item_2
    Submenu_item_3
Menu_parent2_item
    Submenu2_item_1
    Submenu2_item_2
    Submenu2_item_3
Menu_parent3_item
    Submenu3_item_1
    Submenu3_item_2
    Submenu3_item_3
```

Put this code inside function.php:

```
function custom_menu_output( $theme_location ) {
    if ( ($theme_location) && ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$theme_location]) ) {
        $menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        $menus = array();

        foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            $pid = $menu_item->menu_item_parent ? $menu_item->menu_item_parent : 0;

            $menus[$pid][] = array(
                'link' => $menu_item->url,
                'title' => $menu_item->title,
                'id' => $menu_item->ID,
            );
        }

        foreach($menus as $key => $menu) {
            if($key == 0)
                echo '<ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">';
            else
                echo '<ul data-menu="submenu-'.$key.'" class="menu__level">';
            foreach($menu as $item) {
                if(isset($menus[$item['id']]))
                    echo '<li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-'.$item['id'].'" href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a></li>';
                else
                    echo '<li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="'.$item['link'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }

    } else {
        $menu_list = '<!-- no menu defined in location "'.$theme_location.'" -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

And use it like this in your template:

```
<?php custom_menu_output('menu_location_name_from_register_nav_menu'); ?>
```

It will generate HTML like this (I've based it on your question description):

```
<ul data-menu="main" class="menu__level">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-717" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Menu_parent1_item</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-720" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Menu_parent2_item</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" data-submenu="submenu-725" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Menu_parent3_item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul data-menu="submenu-717" class="menu__level">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu_item_1</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu_item_2</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu_item_3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul data-menu="submenu-720" class="menu__level">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_1</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_2</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul data-menu="submenu-725" class="menu__level">
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_1</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_2</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="http://yourdomain.tld/your_link/">Submenu2_item_3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can further customize this code for your needs.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I approached this wrongly by thinking that walker class was the only way to go.. Thank you!

Comment: if i have 3 level menu in wordpress then how can I show the menus on hover on li items who has sub-menu, please share css or other sutffs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use walker class to make the changes in ul and li strcuture.

```
class themeslug_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {


        private $color_idx = 0;

        // add classes to ul sub-menus
        function start_lvl( &$output, $depth) {
            //p($output);
            // depth dependent classes
            $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
            $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
            $classes = array(
                'sidebar-menu',
                ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
                ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
                'level-' . $display_depth
                );
            $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

            $back_btn = '';
            if($display_depth > 0){

                /*$parent_label = '<li class="top custom-row">
                                    <a class="close-menu" href="#"><span class="parent_label"></span><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                  </li>';

                $back_btn = '<li class="sidebar-item back no-children back'.$display_depth.'">
                              <div class="inner">
                                <a class="hit-area" href="#">Back</a>
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                              </div>
                            </li>';*/
            }

            // build html
            $incri = $this->color_idx-1;
            $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="menu__level" data-menu="submenu-'.$incri.'">' .$parent_label.$back_btn. "\n";
        }

        // add main/sub classes to li's and links
         function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {


            global $wp_query;
            $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

            // depth dependent classes
            /*$depth_classes = array(
                'sidebar-item',
                ( $depth == 0 ? 'li0' : '' ),
                ( $depth == 1 ? 'li1' : '' ),
                ( $depth == 2 ? 'li2' : '' ),
                ( $depth == 3 ? 'li3' : '' ),
                /*( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
                'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
            );*/



            if(in_array('menu-item-has-children',$item->classes)){
                $has_children = 'data-has-children="1"';
                $has_children_var = 1;
                $depth_classes[] = 'has-children';
            } else{
                $has_children_var = 0;
                $depth_classes[] = 'no-children';
            }


            $li_attributes = 'data-level="'.$depth.'" data-title="'.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).'" '.$has_children;



            $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );




            // passed classes
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

            // build html
            $output .= $indent . '<li class="menu__item">';

            // link attributes

            $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
            if($has_children_var == 1){
                $attributes .= ' data-submenu="submenu-'.$this->color_idx.'"';
            } 
            $attributes .= ' class="menu__link"';


            $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
                $args->before,
                $attributes,
                $args->link_before,
                apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
                ($has_children_var == 1 ? $args->link_after : ''),
                $args->after
            );

            // build html
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

            if($has_children_var == 1){
                $this->color_idx++;
            }
        }

    }
```

But it doesn't provide a method to separate the submenu ul from the parent li.

Else all the classes like `submenu-1, submenu-2` can be managed.

Try modifying this code.

For reference see this website [Energy & Manpower](http://energymanpower.com/)

The right side menu when clicked on the menu button on the right side of the page is build in same way

Comment: Or you will have to create separate menus from the back-end for each ul and assign them the classes and data-attributes via walker class

Comment: This is pretty close what I'm trying to do. But to get that specific Tympanus Blueprint menu to work those submenus have to be separate. I already tried to put it like your code example but it is kind of laggy with that structure. But if there isn't coming any new answers I might have to use different approach to my menu structure. :)